# How to transform xml with XSLT using AWS lambda(C#)?

Tags: c#, xslt, aws-lambda

I developed code in AWS lambda using C#, .NET Core framework.
I have to transform XML(input string to my lambda function) with XSLT(hard coded in my lambda code) in my lambda code. in order to do so i tried use System.Xml.Xsl but after investigation I understood that .Net Core doesn't support System.Xml.Xsl library.
how can i do it otherwise?

Comment: Consider adding a tag for that platform/environment (AWS lamda) so that people with some knowledge on that can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44157694/804385) in details, **you need to upgrade your `.NET Core 1.x` app to `.NET Core 2.0`**, because `.NET Core 2.0` implements `.NET Standard 2.0`, which has `System.Xml.Xsl` namespace supported again. And you will be able to use `XslTransform` or `XslCompiledTransform` as we did before with `.NET Frameworks`

Comment: But as i saw in AWS Lambda Function documentation, it supports .NET Core 1.0 only, not so?

Comment: @Dindin yes, "AWS Lambda will skip .NET Core 1.1 in flavor to .NET Core 2.0 which is going to be released this year" https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/572

As a workaround until it's released, you could consider to move XSL related logic to separate WebAPI app (.NET Core 2.0) for example and call APIs from your AWS Lambda Function logic via HttpClient for example.