# How to transform XML to HTML with XSLT in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How can I transform XML to HTML with XSLT in ASP.NET Core?

I thought about:

```
public static string TransformXMLToHTML(string inputXml, string xsltString)
{
    XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
    using(XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xsltString))) {
        transform.Load(reader);
    }
    StringWriter results = new StringWriter();
    using(XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(inputXml))) {
        transform.Transform(reader, null, results);
    }
    return results.ToString();
}
```

but the XmlReader does not exist in .NET Core.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

The `System.Xml.Xsl` disappeared in `.NET Core 1.0` as `XSD (XmlSchema)` or `XSLT (XslTransform)` is not supported in `.NET Standard 1.0`, which `.NET Core` implements until version '.NET Core 2.0'. **Good news are that since `.NET Core 2.0`** it implements `.NET Standard 2.0`, so **we have `System.Xml.Xsl` again**.

> If you are confused with all of these `standards`, `frameworks` and
>   `platforms`, watch the video in this post [.NET Standard 2.0 is out and it’s impressive!!!!](http://www.talkingdotnet.com/whats-new-in-net-standard-2/) and see the [.NET Standard Versions](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions.md) table
>   to understand what platforms implement what .NET standards and what is supported in each new version.

So to answer your question, **you need to upgrade your `.NET Core` app to `.NET Core 2.0`** and your code will work again.

```
public static string TransformXMLToHTML(string inputXml, string xsltString)
{
    XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
    using(XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xsltString))) {
        transform.Load(reader);
    }
    StringWriter results = new StringWriter();
    using(XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(inputXml))) {
        transform.Transform(reader, null, results);
    }
    return results.ToString();
}
```

If you need to return `XDocument` you can the code below, which is similar to your but return instance of 'XML' document:

```
public XDocument Transform(string xml, string xsl)
{
    var originalXml = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(xml));

    var transformedXml = new XDocument();
    using (var xmlWriter = transformedXml.CreateWriter())
    {
        var xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
        xslt.Load(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xsl)));

        // Add XSLT parameters if you need
        XsltArgumentList xsltArguments = null; // new XsltArgumentList();
        // xsltArguments.AddParam(name, namespaceUri, parameter);

        xslt.Transform(originalXml.CreateReader(), xsltArguments, xmlWriter);
    }

    return transformedXml;
}
```