# Load XSLT in Asp.Net Core

Tags: .net, xml, xslt, asp.net-core

How can I load XSLT file from string in ASP.NET Core?

In full .NET Framework I can use:

```
XslCompiledTransform objXSLTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();    
objXSLTransform.Load(strXSLTFile);
```

Comment: iirc it's not implemented yet in .NET Core and you'll have to wait till .NET Core 2.0. Or grab the current 2.0 preview. Or just target .NET Framework >=4.5. Also see this issue https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/5593

Comment: @Tseng Can I find some 3rd part library?

Comment: Not that I am aware off (besides out of scope of SO).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44157694/804385) in details, **you need to upgrade your `.NET Core 1.x` app to `.NET Core 2.0`**, because `.NET Core 2.0` implements `.NET Standard 2.0`, which has `System.Xml.Xsl` namespace supported again. And you will be able to use `XslCompiledTransform` again.