# Background color is not getting applied to a Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, xslt

I am using XML and XSLT and transforming it to HTML. and passing the html content to a javascript function. but the problem is the style class is getting called and line-through and underlines are getting applied but not the background color, i also used !important still the background color is not applying .
Can anyone help me on this.

```
My function

 $(function () {
            
            $("#Button1").click(function () {
                
                $('#displayCompare2').addClass('ins','del');
                var original = document.getElementById("displayCompare").innerHTML;
                var changed = document.getElementById("displayCompare2").innerHTML;

                let output = htmldiff(original, changed);
                
                document.getElementById("displayCompare2").innerHTML = output;
            })
        })
```

My style class

```
     .ins {
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: #d4fcbc;
      }

    .del {
        
        text-decoration: line-through;          
        background-color: #fbb6c2 ;

    }
```

My XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>

      <body >
        <xsl:for-each select="table/tr">
          <div style="padding:4px">

            <span style="font-weight:bold;">
              <xsl:value-of select="td1"/>
            </span>

          </div>
          <div style="padding:4px" >
            <xsl:if test="not(contains(td2, '|'))">
              <xsl:value-of select="td2"/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="contains(td2, '|')">

              <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(td2, '|')"/>

            </xsl:if>
          </div>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: `$('#response2id').addClass('ins','del');` isn't valid. Check console.

Comment: $('.response2id').addClass('inc del');

Comment: [`addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/#addClass-className) - *One or more **space-separated** classes to be added to the class attribute of each matched element.*

Comment: @pavel it's not a syntax error, so there would not be a message in the console, just the 2nd parameter ignored.

Comment: Pavan ,Freedomn and chirag Thanks for you quick reply , i tried $('.response2id').addClass('inc del'); still same result only text decoration is getting applied

Comment: Your code *as provided* (ignoring all of what appears to be irrelevant xlst stuff) and with the fix applied, works fine:  https://jsfiddle.net/1rjuf5kt/   Note that you're using `$('#response2id').addClass` ie `id=response2id` (which isn't included in your question) - if you have multiple of these, only the first will be applied as IDs must be unique.   Your next step is to provide a [mcve] - with the **code relevant to the problem** - ie something that at least includes #response2id.  Maybe it's in `htmldiff`, in which case provide a link to that library.

Comment: oh i am sorry it should be  $('#displayCompare2').addClass('ins','del');   its a label id. i am getting the content from cs file and passing it to labels and the comparing the content of label 1 and label 2 using javascript where its uses these style classes ins and del

Comment: But even after correcting still its not working

Comment: What does the JavaScript code to run the XSLT look like? Is the problem occurring in several browsers or only certain ones?

Comment: i used xslt to transform the xml into html and that output html i need to pass as a input to htmldiff javascript function, basically i am comparing 2 htmls and display differences

Comment: please verify my xslt is it overwriting my styles , but i have removed all styles from xslt and checked still only background color is not getting applied .

Comment: It is not clear how you mix XSLT, JavaScript, HTML and CSS, if you don't show a minimal but complete sample that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: For XML To Html tranformation i followed  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43323465/how-to-transform-xml-to-html-with-xslt-in-c . and for comparing two htmls i followed - https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/653/how-to-diff-html-compare-and-highlight-differences-and-generate-output-in-html-with-javascript . here to compare 2 htmls i need the html as an input so i transformed xml to html (pls refer first link). please let me know for more clarification

Comment: i am getting this error while debugging Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' near this line  background-color: #d4fcbc;

Comment: Hi All this has been solved by adding styles separately $('ins').addClass('ins');                               
$('del').addClass('del');  Thanks for all your support :)